# OData query for Azure Graph API?

Tags: authorization, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

Could someone help with the OData query for the isMemeberOf API on the Azure GraphAPI

Here is the reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#isMemberOf

I am looking for a sample oData query to be able to run on the demo
https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany

For the below scenarios:
"groupId": "5e624f44-d38d-4943-b07c-2bad078f52ff",
"memberId": "ea59e4d3-a7a1-4b5b-b65f-a25fcc0c0f99"

Wondering if it is possible to query with the group name and the memberId as below

"displayName": "SampleSecurityGroup",
"memberId": "ea59e4d3-a7a1-4b5b-b65f-a25fcc0c0f99"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, realized the IsMemberOf method exposed on the Graph API takes only groupId and memberId. I had to get the memberId using the display name and use it for the IsMemberOf call.